# VB6 - Select all items from external program Listview

Tags: listview, vb6, external, selectall

I have to select all items from an external program Listview control.
Does anybody know how can I accomplish this?
I tried with SendCommand, but failed.

In AutoIt I can do it this way:

```
ControlListView("Title", "", "[CLASS:SysListView32; INSTANCE:1]", "Selectall")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to send a message to the control using with Win32 [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

There is an [example of exactly this right here](http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/comctl/lvselectall.htm).

You will of course have to find the window handle of the control, provided you know the class and window name (which you can find with [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)) you can probably do it with [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I managed to use just LVM_GETSELECTEDCOUNT to get the number of selected items from my listview. The LVM_SETITEMSTATE gives me an "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: @Stan: You are using incompatible `SendMessage` on your second call. Update question with some code if you need more pointers.